# Dynamically generated HTML code and window.open function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is 2003 VB code (asp.net) that I converted to VS 2010. It used to work fine in VS2003. Currently running on dotnet framework 4.0 with IIS 7.5

There is a function `setdate` that ia defined in the    `<head>`     section of an aspx page

```
<script language="javaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function setDate(date) {       
      window.opener.document.getElementById("txtDueDate").value = date;
      window.close();
    }
</script>
```

The call to this function is dynamically generated HTML code that is inserted into the DOM. 
When I view the source code I see that this code has been inserted before the ending form tag

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">setDate('5/22/2013');</script>
  </form>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     var yTop = (screen.availHeight - document.body.clientHeight) / 2;
     var xLeft = (screen.availWidth - document.body.clientWidth) / 2;
     window.moveTo(xLeft, yTop);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I put an alert box in the `setDate` function it shows up with the correct value for `date`, but the function is not populating the parent window.

Not sure why. Please help

Comment: and if you comment out the close line and open up the JavaScript console on the browser, what is the error message that appears?

Comment: STOP EDITING YOUR POST! The ` is not used in code blocks.

Comment: There is no error. The parent window does not get populated and the popup window does not close.

Comment: I am still sure there should be an error. Wrap it in a try catch... `function setDate(date) { try { window.opener.document.getElementById("txtDueDate").value = date;
      window.close(); } catch(e){ console.log(e) };
    }`

Comment: There is no error. But aomething that I noticed is that when I run the app. from VS 2010 it is working now, but when I run the app from the browser URL --- http://h02123/Torders/ it does not work.